# Building Oculus Mobile VR SDK with Eclipse: VrApi module already defined

Tags: eclipse, mobile, sdk, oculus, virtual-reality

I am building a blank project in Eclipse with the Oculus Mobile VR SDK. I am getting the following error:

```
Android NDK: Trying to define local module 'vrapi' in jni/../../../../../../VrApi/Projects/AndroidPrebuilt/jni/Android.mk.    
Android NDK: But this module was already defined by jni/../../../../../../VrApi/Projects/AndroidPrebuilt/jni/Android.mk.
```

Looks like that Android.mk is somehow included twice. I'm using Oculus Mobile VR SDK 0.6.2.0. The following projects are included in my Eclipse workspace:

LibOVRKernel_Prebuilt
MediaSurface
VrApi_Prebuilt
VrAppFramework_Prebuilt
VrGUI
VrLocale
VrSound

Tried re-creating the workspace twice, but still the same error. How can vrapi module be included twice? The only Android.mk where it says

```
LOCAL_MODULE := vrapi
```

is in VrApi_Prebuilt and nowhere else.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by modifying Android.mk inside VrApi_Prebuilt in the following way.

I added

```
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

right before the following block:

```
ifneq (,$(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(LOCAL_SRC_FILES)))
  include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
endif
```

I removed .so extension from

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../../../Libs/Android/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/lib$(LOCAL_MODULE).so
```

Hence, the line becomes

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../../../Libs/Android/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/lib$(LOCAL_MODULE)
```